# bind_rows , lapply run faster

Tags: r

I have a list of files which need same operations/treatments on them. I have created a bunch of functions for that, for example,

NameFunc : extract name and other particulars from the title

AnalysisFunc : running some analysis on the files and generating an output df which also adds above particulars
A few other functions as well

I then created a master function as such

```
Output_df <- bind_rows(lapply(files, function(x){
print(x)
df_x <- load(x)
df1 <- NameFunc(df_x)
df2 <- AnalysisFunc(df_x)
df3 <- Projections(df_x)
df <- cbind(df1, df2, df3)

return(df)}
```

I have over 25,000 files. My code is taking a lot of time to execute. Is there a way to expedite the run time?

Comment: We dont know what `NameFunc` `AnalysisFunc` and `Projections` do, or which library they're from. So its not possible to say for sure if we can optimize any of those. But  you should remove `print`. Printing is **very** slow, (try comparing `for(i in 1:1e5)print(i)` vs `for(i in 1:1e5)invisible(i)`). Next I would look at the 3 functions in question using `profvis` and/or `benchmark` to see which can be optimized. Or if I'm in a hurry, use `parallel::parLapply` instead of `lapply` to run the ELT process in parallel. Note this is only possible if they are completely independent!

Comment: For completeness: `system.time(for(i in 1:1e5)print(i))` -> `elapsed: 8.38` and `system.time(for(i in 1:1e5)invisible(i))` -> `elapsed: 0.02` on my pc.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the nested call on a small subset of files and seeing where the bottlenecks are?